# Logistic regression gives very confusing results in SPSS

Tags: regression, logistic, spss, binary-data, ordinal-data

While analyzing the data for my bachelor thesis, I got some results that I just don't know how to make sense of. I've been trying to predict a binary variable (yes/no choice in a questionnaire) from a variable (dark personality factor) that can be split up into 4 subcomponents (callousness, vindictiveness, deceitfulness, and sadism) which are each coded into a 1-5 point scale. When I perform a logistic regression for each of the factors separately, they all come out as significant predictors:

[image: individual predictors]

However, when I create a model where they're all included together, all of the sudden none of them are significant:

[image]

How can this be? Does it mean that the variables somehow cancel each other out?

It gets even more confusing: When I combine the four components into one*, then that one is all of the sudden highly significant:

[image: dark factor]

I'm really confused by those results. If all of the components are significant individually, why aren't they significant anymore when you put them together in a model? Is it that maybe because they have a high correlation between each other? And why is it significant again when you code them together into one variable? Shouldn't it be more or less the same result as when I put them together in one model?
If any of you have any idea what I am missing here, It would really help me out a ton if you could give me some pointers.

Thank you!

*The four components were part of a 16-question questionnaire. I combined the components into one by just taking the average of the scores from all 16 questions. What's maybe also important to know is that there wasn't an equal amount of questions for all components: Only 1 question out of the questionnaire was for Deceitfulness; the other three components were calculated by 5 questions each.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated. To provide some additional information that may be useful, could you please explain how you combine the four components into one.

Comment: Yes, thanks for your comment. The four components were part of a 16-question questionnaire. I just took the average of the scores from all 16 questions. What's maybe also important to know is that there wasn't an equal amount of questions for all components: 1 question out of the questionnaire was for Deceitfulness; the other three components were each calculated by 5 questions.